# Array of Instances, how to know what's the index of a particular instance in the array

Tags: system-verilog

I am using system verilog for synthesis. I have an array of interface instances. Inside the interface definition, I want a parameter which can tell what's the index of this instance in the array. I think we can't pass different parameter values to each different instances in the array. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: how exactly did you create an array of instances?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no automatic way of doing this for synthesizable code with an array of instances. You can manually do it using `defparam` if your synthesis tool supports it.

```
module dut#(int I=0);
  initial $display("%m",,I);
endmodule

module top;
  dut u[1:2] ();
  defparam u[1].I=1;
  defparam u[2].I=2;
endmodule
```

A better way would be using a generate-for loop.

```
module dut#(int I);
  initial $display("%m",,I);
endmodule

module top;
  for(genvar i=1;i<=2;i++) begin : A
    dut #(.I(i)) u();
  end : A
endmodule : top
```